# Excel VBA: Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script that copies data from rows in the `SoapUI - Single` Sheet to a `STpremcalc` Sheet and then copies the final calculation back over to `SoapUI - Single` Sheet. It works fine but I have 10000 rows of data and it takes around 30 seconds to do one row. When I tested it with 1000 rows it finished within a minute.

What is causing this? Is it because the VBA script is reading the whole worksheet before if copies the values across.

```
Sub SingleRating()
Dim i As Long
Dim iteration As Variant
Dim seleciton As Variant
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("SoapUI - Single")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("STpremcalc")

iteration = 0
iteration = InputBox("Please Select Row Iteration", "", "1000")
seleciton = iteration + 2

    For i = 3 To seleciton
        ws2.Range("B3").Value = ws1.Range("B" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B4").Value = ws1.Range("C" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B5").Value = ws1.Range("D" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B6").Value = ws1.Range("E" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("E3").Value = ws1.Range("F" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("E4").Value = ws1.Range("G" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("E5").Value = ws1.Range("H" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("E6").Value = ws1.Range("I" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("G3").Value = ws1.Range("J" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("G4").Value = ws1.Range("K" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("G5").Value = ws1.Range("L" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("J3").Value = ws1.Range("N" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("J4").Value = ws1.Range("O" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("J6").Value = ws1.Range("P" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B9:E9").Value = ws1.Range("Q" & i, "T" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B10:E10").Value = ws1.Range("U" & i, "X" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B11:E11").Value = ws1.Range("Y" & i, "AB" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B12:E12").Value = ws1.Range("AC" & i, "AF" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B13:E13").Value = ws1.Range("AG" & i, "AJ" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B14:E14").Value = ws1.Range("AK" & i, "AN" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B15:E15").Value = ws1.Range("AO" & i, "AR" & i).Value

        ws2.Range("B16:E16").Value = ws1.Range("AS" & i, "AV" & i).Value

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ws1.Range("AW" & i).Value = ws2.Range("M4").Value

        ws1.Range("AX" & i).Value = ws2.Range("M5").Value

        ws1.Range("AY" & i).Value = ws2.Range("M6").Value

        Application.StatusBar = "Current iteration: " & (i - 2) & "/" & iteration
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Since this is _working code_, it's an excellent candidate for [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you *need* to copy the data back and forth? The data writes are definitely what's hurting your execution time. It looks like cells STpremcalc!M4:M6 are carrying out calculations based on the values in the sheet, and that all you really want is the output of these cells. If you can figure out the calculation they're doing and port it over to run in VBA instead of executing on the worksheet, you'll get some nice speedups by skipping the majority of the data manipulation.

Comment: @Mikegrann The Calculation sheet has about 100 - 150 different calculations to come to the final number. so it would take a while to set it up. I thought this was would be quicker as the formulas are all already set.

Comment: It's faster to set up this way - obviously it takes a lot less code to shuffle some numbers around. But I'm betting you'll get some good speedups if you run the calculations yourself instead of relying on the worksheet to evaluate things for you. I guess it just depends on how much of your time it's worth to put in the work to get that all coded. It might be more efficient for you to just live with the execution times instead of wasting a day coding? Depends on how often you need to run this operation.

Answer (score 3):

If that is your whole code I'd suggest inserting this right after initializing your variables:

```
screenUpdateState = Application.ScreenUpdating

statusBarState = Application.DisplayStatusBar

calcState = Application.Calculation

eventsState = Application.EnableEvents

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.EnableEvents = False
```

At the very end of your code (above End Sub) reverse it:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = screenUpdateState

Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState

Application.Calculation = calcState

Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
```

From my experience especially the ScreenUpdating part gives a massive performance boost when copying / inserting rows. If you still have performance problems after disabling it, we need to look at the implementation itself.

I think this should help you though, as I have copied tens of thousand rows between worksheets and never had a performance issue.

Comment: I get the same values for all the rows?

Comment: You should. The manual calculation mode may cause a difference depending on the exact setup of your workbooks. I'd suggest trying all of the options and then check if the values are the same as before (should be done rather fast with Excel). If the values differ, try throwing out the Application.Calculation setting.